# Passing an object as prop in React-Router Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass object props to Payments component using render method in route.

I have tried pass props to the functional components, but still no luck.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: {},
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "/api/current-user";
    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "same-origin",
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          return response.json().then((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((results) => {
        const user = results.user;
        this.setState({
          user,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.user);
    
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="is-size-3">Test</h1>
        {this.state.user && (
          <Route
            exact
            path="/payments"
            render={(props) => <Payments {...props} user={this.state.user} /> }
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Payments.js**

```
function Payments() {
  return (
    <>
      <CheckoutForm user={this.props.user} />
      <CurrentSubscription subscription={subscription} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried a few approaches,but still I'm getting 'props' of undefined.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want props of App.js component passed to Payment.js component??? or just this.state.user??

Comment: Props of App.js

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function Payments(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <CheckoutForm user={props.user} />
      <CurrentSubscription subscription={subscription} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always put props in the function or class component f you have props, like so:

```
function Payments({user}) {
  return (
    <>
      <CheckoutForm user={user} />
      <CurrentSubscription subscription={subscription} />
    </>
  );
}
```

or

```
function Payments(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <CheckoutForm user={props.user} />
      <CurrentSubscription subscription={subscription} />
    </>
  );
}
```

By the way, in functional component, there's no `this`.